# Web hosting/domain confusion

Tags: domain, web-hosting

I have a domain registered at 123-reg.  The domain is mahsc-ctu.co.uk

Here's my problem.  When I type http://mahsc-ctu.co.uk I get the holding page provided by my hosting company, but when I type http://www.mahsc-ctu.co.uk I get the holding page provided by 123-reg.

Why is this happening and how do I go about fixing it?

Here are my DNS records:-

[image]

Where do I go from here?  Wierd thing is, the destination/target is set to the 123-reg host, not my site...  Is this because I've been trying things and it's taking a while to propagate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find that during testing of this, web caching may result in you seeing the wrong page.  Your browser/OS probably has a local cache, which you can usually bypass by pressing CTRL+F5 to refresh the page.  It isn't that likely that a cache outside you control (e.g. your place of work, or your ISP) has cached content for the URL, but not impossible.

You can also fall foul of DNS cacheing.  You can clear your local DNS cache in Windows by typing `ipconfig /flushdns` and then see whether re-loading the page results in the content you expect.  Again, there may be DNS cache in between you and the nameservers for this domain, and they can cause problems too based on the TTL for the record.

Finally, it can take some time for DNS changes to be reflected globally (up to 48 hours) so there is a chance that you won't see the results of your change for some time.

From what I can see your settings are correct, so probably you just need to wait a while - generally it is a lot less than 48 hours.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have two different A records for each domain, for instance you have:

- One A record for mahsc-ctu.co.uk pointing to your hosting IP address
- One A record for www.mahsc-ctu.co.uk pointing to your 123-reg provider

You may want to delete the www.mahsc-ctu.co.uk record and either create an CNAME alias pointing to mahsc-ctu.co.uk or create an *.mahsc-ctu.co.uk pointing to your hosting IP address

Update:

The easier way to solve it is to create an CNAME record www.mahsc-ctu.co.uk -> mahsc-ctu.co.uk, your problem comes for the lack of the www.mahsc-ctu.co.uk record.

Comment: I've updated my question as I'm getting really confused..

Comment: What would I enter for the DNS ENTRY, TYPE, and DESTINATION/TARGET bits then?

Comment: www.mahsc-ctu.co.uk is a subdomain on mahsc-ctu.co.uk - so they are the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a DNS entry for *.mahsc-ctu.co.uk which would point www.mahsc-ctu.co.uk at your web hosts. It sounds like currently you have only a DNS pointer record for mahsc-ctu.co.uk.

Try adding an A record for * that points to your server IP address.

Update:

The easier way to solve it is to create an CNAME record www.mahsc-ctu.co.uk -> mahsc-ctu.co.uk, your problem comes for the lack of the www.mahsc-ctu.co.uk record.

Comment: I've updated my question as I'm getting very confused.

Comment: Is the IP address 81.21.76.62 your server or 123-reg?